# How to remove the following unicode from a string in r?

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string `7007756484480000000<U+2660>75,648,448`
I want to remove `7007756484480000000<U+2660>` and the commas
I have been trying many different ways other have shown here but I am not getting it. If someone could help, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Well, here's the problem. That's _not_ a Unicode character in an R string. So learning how to remove "real" R Unicode characters won't help. You should post the output of `dput(x)` where x is the name of an R object.

Comment: Punched reopen to get this off the audit queue. It's not a fair audit question.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that there is a language barrier to expression of a clear problem but if I am reading the request it is to remove both "7007756484480000000" as well as "," from that string. The first argument (the `pattern`) to the regex function `gsub` will accept a logical OR when written inside a pattern string as `"|"`, so we can replace any such instances with `""`:

```
> x <- "700775648448000000075,648,448"
> gsub("7007756484480000000|,","",x)
[1] "75648448"
```

For the revised problem (if that really is what the string looks like when displayed in R) you could remove everything up to right-angle-bracket and commas with:

```
gsub("(^.+>)|,",   # match either a comma or (everything from start to the ">")
      "",          # replace with empty string
      "7007756484480000000<U+2660>75,648,448")   # the input
```

A real Unicode character would look like this:

```
 z <- "\U2660"
 nchar(z)
#[1] 1
# whereas you just have ordinary characters
 z <- "<U+2660>"
 nchar(z)
#[1] 8
```

If it had been a "real" Unicode character in an R character vector it could have been removed in one of two ways, either using a character class mechanism or using the necessary double (and in this case triple backslashing) which becomes necessary because R and PCRE share an escape character ("|"):

```
z <- "\U2660"
z
#[1] "♠"
gsub("\\U2660","",z)
#[1] "♠"
gsub("\\U2660","",z)
#[1] "♠"

#Method 1
gsub("[\U2660]","",z)
#[1] ""

#Method 2
 gsub("\\\U2660","",z)
#[1] ""
```

Comment: I am sorry. I am new here. I have fixed the question. Still thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!